# How should I select the next item to process when running processors in parallel?

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, parallel-processing, elasticsearch

I'm asking this question without database specifics because it feels like the answer may lie in a common design pattern, and I don't necessarily need a system specific solution ( my specific system setup is referenced at the end of the question ).

I've got a database of companies containing an id, a url, and a processing field, to indicate whether or not that company is currently being processed by one of my crawlers.  I run many crawlers in parallel. Each one needs to select a company to process and set that company as processing before it starts so that each company is only being processed by a single crawler at any given time.

**How should I structure my system to keep track of what companies are being processed?**

The challenge here is that I cannot search my database for a company that is not being processed and then update that company to set it as processed, because another crawler may have chosen it in the meantime. This seems like something that must be a common problem when processing data in parallel so I'm looking for a theoretical best practice.

I used to use MySQL for this and used the following code to maintain consistency between my processors.  I'm redesigning the system, however, and now ElasticSearch is going to be my main database and search server. The MySQL solution below always felt like a hack to me and not a proper solution to this paralellization problem.

```
public function select_next()
{

    // set a temp variable that allows us to retrieve id of the row that is updated during next query
    $sql = 'SET @update_id := 0';
    $Result = $this->Mysqli->query( $sql );
    if( ! $Result )
        die( "\n\n    " . $this->Mysqli->error . "\n" . $sql );

    // selects next company to be crawled, marks as crawling in the db
    $sql = "UPDATE companies
            SET
                crawling = 1,
                id = ( SELECT @update_id := id )
            WHERE crawling = 0
            ORDER BY last_crawled ASC, id ASC
            LIMIT 1";
    $Result = $this->Mysqli->query( $sql );
    if( ! $Result )
        die( "\n\n    " . $this->Mysqli->error . "\n" . $sql );

    // this query returned at least one result and there are companies to be crawled
    if( $this->Mysqli->affected_rows > 0 )
    {

        // gets the id of the row that was just updated in the previous query
        $sql = 'SELECT @update_id AS id';
        $Result = $this->Mysqli->query( $sql );
        if( ! $Result )
            die( "\n\n    " . $this->Mysqli->error . "\n" . $sql );

        // set company id
        $this->id = $Result->fetch_object()->id;

    }

}
```

Comment: Generally speaking you should be able to do this by using proper locking mechanisms. MySQL has some not sure about ElasticSearch. However you should be able to place a exclusive lock on a row being updated to ensure that it cannot be changed while you are updating it. This is one of the main properties of a ACID compliant database. Best check ElasticSearch documentation on how its locking works and how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that is often used for such problems is sharding. You can define a deterministic function that assigns each row in the database to a crawler. In your case, such function can simply be a company id modulo number of crawlers. Each crawler can sequentially process companies that belong to this worker shard, which guarantees no companies are ever processed simultaneously.

Such approach is used for example by Reduce part of [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Partition_function).

An advantage is that no transactions or locking are required which are hard to implement and often are a bottleneck, especially in a distributed environment. A disadvantage is that work can be partitioned not equally between crawlers, in which case some crawlers are idle when others are still processing.